# Possible Ways to refer a commit

Tags: git

Would like to find different ways that we can refer to a commit in git. Could anyone please let me know what are the different ways that we can refer to a commit in git?

Comment: Could you explain your problem better?

Comment: Run `git revisions --help` or read [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.con/docs/gitrevisions).

Comment: the sha value??

Comment: @ElpieKay late correction, `git help revisions`, revisions is a help topic not a command.

Comment: @jthill Thanks for correction. It once worked, but now it's not a valid command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ways git refer a commit :

1. commits are referred as relative to one another. For instance `HEAD~1` would refer to the commit parent of HEAD.
2. refspecs can be used to refer commits that reside on remote branches using local Git environment.
3. Every tags created in repository would become a ref, which Git would maintain certain commits alias's.
4. Git's commit hash can be used to refer corresponding commits.

Answer (score 1):

As a Git newbie it took me a while to parse Rishi's explanation, so let me tell you my interpretation:

- The word `HEAD` refers to the most recent commit.

**Example:**

```
git show HEAD:content.js
```

- Appending `~` and a number refers to the nth commit before that one.  So `HEAD~2` is the commit two steps before HEAD.

**Example:**

```
git show HEAD~2:content.js
```

- You can use the hash of a commit to refer to it, or even the first part of the hash (so long as it is unique).  You can find your commits' hashes by typing  `git log --reflog`; the hash looks like `d8c01a835cd2d345703914c3302632bbfb1f0c58`. You can type that all out, or you can refer to it as `d8c01`, or as many characters from the beginning that work. (I got four to work; I don't know if that is a global minimum or not.)

**Example:**

```
git show d8c01a83:content.js
```

- You can use the `git tag` command to give a tag to a commit, which can be referred to later.  So `git tag v1` gives the current commit the tag `v1`.  You can also name previous commits, like `git tag v1 d8c01`. **Example:**

```
git tag v1 d8c01
git show v1:content.js
```

- Lastly, refspecs are (I believe) things like `origin/main` which refer to the current commit on the remote server.

**Example:**

```
git show origin/master:content.js
```